# Why do browsers need to be told the encoding of a file?

Tags: browser, encoding

According to [this documentation](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php) (among many other places, I'm sure), it's very important to declare the character encoding used in a given file for the browser.

Most text editors (and programs like `file`) seem to auto detect the character encoding of a file without trouble.

Why do browsers need this information declared in the file?

*They do seem guess pretty well when no encoding is declared, but often still seem to fail on "special" characters.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't *need* it, but it's recommended to give that information, since guessing the wrong charset may

- result in an unreadable page (only partly or completely the whole page)
- introduce possible vulnerabilities to the system

## "There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text."

Before the advent of Unicode, computers use various [codepages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) and [encoding schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) to record different scripts. Unfortunately the bad thing is that no encoding information is embedded in the file. That situation won't disappear and different character sets and encodings will continue to exist. A text editor will have to open the text file with the appropriate encoding to get the real codepoints and then render it in the correct charset. However since they have no idea what encoding the file is in, they have to [**guess**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset_detection) it using heuristic

> This algorithm usually involves statistical analysis of byte patterns, like frequency distribution of trigraphs of various languages encoded in each code page that will be detected; such statistical analysis can also be used to perform language detection.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset_detection

Firefox uses the [Mozilla Charset Detectors](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/chardet.html). The way it works is explained [here](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html) and you can also [change its heuristic preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Localizations_and_character_encodings). Chrome previously used [ICU detector](https://github.com/mooz/node-icu-charset-detector) but switched to [CED](https://opensource.google.com/projects/ced) almost [2 years ago](https://codereview.chromium.org/2081653007)

[Update: Firefox moved to [chardetng](https://hsivonen.fi/chardetng/) since Firefox 73]

Most of the time they will guess the encodings correctly, but the algorithms work better for words so they may fail for many symbols. Unicode encodings are generally easier to guess due to the way UTF-8/16/32 are encoded. You can also force an encoding by putting a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning.

But overall there's no way to guess all encodings and charsets reliably, as the same byte stream may be valid in multiple encodings at the same time. In the end they may make mistakes [like this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91487), because it's just guessing anyway! That's also how the famous [Bush hid the facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) bug occurred in pre-Vista Notepad, when the API `IsTextUnicode` thinks that a plain ASCII text file is a UTF-16LE file as the file content also looks OK in UTF-16LE.

Bad guessing also introduces a vulnerability to the system like The Google UTF-7 exploit in David's answer. As a result, the encoding should always be explicitly stated.

The good thing is that most charsets agree with each other about the first 127 codepoints, so browsers can just read the first bytes from the header with the default (or any appropriate) charset until it sees the charset option inside `meta` tag. If the charset was wrong then it will reopen the file using the given charset in the file content.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Read more:

- [Joel on Software's The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- [Unicode, UTF-8 and character encodings: What every developer should know](http://www.teknically-speaking.com/2014/02/unicode-utf-8-and-character-encodings_23.html)

Answer (score 1):

Reference [UTF-8: The Secret of Character Encoding](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html)

> **No embedded encoding**
>
> If this is the case, you'll want to add in the appropriate META tag to
>   your website. It's as simple as copy-pasting the code snippet above
>   and replacing UTF-8 with whatever is the mime name of your real
>   encoding.
>
> For all those skeptics out there, there is a very good reason why the character encoding should be explicitly stated. **When the browser
>   isn't told what the character encoding of a text is, it has to guess:
>   and sometimes the guess is wrong. Hackers can manipulate this guess in
>   order to slip XSS past filters and then fool the browser into
>   executing it as active code. A great example of this is the Google
>   UTF-7 exploit.**
>
> You might be able to get away with not specifying a character encoding with the META tag as long as your webserver sends the right
>   Content-Type header, but why risk it? Besides, if the user downloads
>   the HTML file, there is no longer any webserver to define the
>   character encoding.